# Package development for Sublime Text 2 with multiple files without restarting

Tags: plugins, package, sublimetext

I am developing a couple of packages for sublime text, and to avoid copy and pasting massive amounts of code I began to move my classes into separate files. I have been avoiding this so far, since, in my current workflow, changes to files that are not in the main plugin file won't get updated when saved and only go into effect when I restart sublime.

Is there a way to reload a package, including all it's files, without restarting Sublime Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have to restart the editor. You will have to restructure your plugins though to take advantage of this. Essentially, you can load the plugin files from some top level file. As an example, take a look at [Package Control](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/blob/master/Package%20Control.py). I also do it in [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight/blob/master/PersistentRegexHighlight.py) (though the package control solution is likely more robust (I did base it on that). Still not as good as simply saving a particular file, but better than restarting! In fact, you could probably tie into the `on_post_save` event to automatically save the top level file when you modify a child file.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much! Right now I am just straight ripping off your reloader.py file, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind saving from a top level file (that is how I had been reloading plugins until I separated it into different files.) What I minded was loosing the ability to undo and the fact that on every restart sublime windows open on different desktops would all open up in one desktop. Brilliant idea though to hook into `on_post_save`, I might give that a go when I have some time on my hand.

Comment: thanks, I actually didn't know about this. So from my understanding of `reloader.py`, it just reloads all of the modules in `sys.modules`, right? How/when does `reloader` get called, then?

Comment: It gets called in the file skuroda linked to in his repository: [PersistentRegexHighlight](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight/blob/master/PersistentRegexHighlight.py). This file has to be a top-level-directory. If you have multiple plugins in the same plugin directory, make sure to list them all in the last `if` statement in the top-level file. Here is how I implemented it: [ClassesAndTests](https://github.com/anconaesselmann/ClassesAndTests/blob/develop/ClassesAndTests.py), pretty much ripped off line by line.

Comment: @MattDMo The reloader is reloaded when the top level file is saved. Recall that the plugin files are "run" when you save them. The reloader then performs the reloads all of the listed files. Well at least that's my understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

I personally found the easiest solution was to install [Package Reloader](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Package%20Reloader), and just put a new file in the top directory of my plugin named `.build`.  Save your top-level plugin file and enjoy not having to restart.

Virtually no restructuring of code required.

Comment: Thanks! Your solutions sounds like it would potentially be more modular, concise, and simpler than the currently accepted answer. I am currently working on something else, but will come back to this eventually, which is when I will give your suggestion a shot. If it works like you claim, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#automatic-plugin-reload):

> Sublime Text will reload top-level Python modules from packages as they change (perhaps because you are editing a .py file). By contrast, Python subpackages won’t be reloaded automatically, and this can lead to confusion while you’re developing plugins. Generally speaking, it’s best to restart Sublime Text after you’ve made changes to plugin files, so all changes can take effect.

Unfortunately, plugins are not loaded into a scope visible from the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>), so you can't just [`reload()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) it. **EDIT** But, you *can* call `reload()` from within your top-level plugin file, as detailed in @skuroda's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532107/1426065).

You'll have to make the decisions on when to break classes out into separate files vs. keeping them together in one monolithic collection. Having 50 files, each with only two or three function definitions is overkill in one direction, while having 20 classes each with 10 or 15 methods all in one file is going overboard in the other, so just do what feels best for the particular project. In my experience killing/restarting ST2 doesn't take too long in any of the supported operating systems (except on XP, for some reason...), so hopefully it's not too much of a delay on your workflow. One suggestion I'd give is to create a portable installation (if you're on Windows) with just the bare essentials in extra plugins if your startup time is too long.

Good luck!